# Python - variable for the scriptroot

Tags: python, variables, root

In powershell you have $PSscriptroot if you want to call a file that is located in the folder of the script you are running - what is the equivalent in python?

Comment: Do you mean the *current working directory*, or the *directory of the file the code is in*?

Comment: As @deceze mentioned + or the directory of the executable ? (which may differ from the directory your code/file is in)

Comment: im asking about the file directory, although the standard working directory would be interesting too - i recall that you could change that by a user config file in powershell